# fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Rruhid/REST-API-php-joins.git/'

Tags: php, windows, authentication, github-api, github-for-windows

Please help me with this problem:
I tried every single step, but nothing helped every time when I try to authenticate it throws me an error, also I type my valid username and generated password.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxZ1e.png)

What I did:

- checked my username $git config --list  // everything is right
- 10  times deleted and updated password and username in credential manager // not helps
- Did a reload on my computer  //not helped
- Changed  URLs from SSH to HTTPS  // by typing git remote set-url origin https://github.com/Rruhid/REST-API-php-joins.git
- deleted everything in .ssl folder
- tried to change it in command prompt  // the program does not allow

NOTHING HELPED. The real problem is - after adding or cloning repository when I push it small with

$ git push -u origin main

it throws an error.

```
  remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
    remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
    fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Rruhid/REST-API-php-joins.git/'
```

My username and password is 100% true.

Answer (score 0):

as the error message says, the password authentication was removed. It means, your password works for login to github GUI, but is useless for push.

What you need to do:

1. Generate access token. This could be helpfull: [Creating a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)
2. Use the token instead of password during push

Remember, save the token for future usage.

Comment: I did it , generated paced but no results 
ghp_RZ19Kbs9xKcpfEbUBffZFMiMK3Taa32J****

Comment: Either for HHTPS or SSH  it requires password from me, although I modified both of them

Comment: Password  of genetic credentials is required,, although I delete it sometimes

Comment: SOLVED WITH  git config --global core.askPass ''

Comment: and are you using token or password for push?